# Querying entries by IDs aggregated by two different tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following table structure

table object_to_profile

```
objectID | profileID
       1 | 1
       2 | 1
       3 | 1
       2 | 2
```

table object_to_task

```
taskID | objectID | profileID
     1 |        1 | 1
     1 |        4 | 1
     1 |        2 | 2
```

The table object_to_task is built the following way:
I show the user checkboxes, which basically represent the object_to_profile table.
The user can select objects out of the table and save them into the object_to_task table.
The Administrator can later remove the object from the table. But if the user has already selected some of the object from the profiles, it should be still visible to him. So I need a query to select all object that are currently in the profiles **plus** all objects that were in the table and have been selected by the user.

As you can see, objectID 4 is no longer in the object_to_profile table, but has been selected by the user.

What would be a way to the objectIDs together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand, you just need to `union` 2 result sets

```
select ObjectID from object_to_profile 
union 
select ObjectID from object_to_task where taskID = 1
```